# Prohibit some words from being saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, reserved-words

- ruby 1.9.2p290
- rails 3.1.1

I have the following routes output:

```
http://localhost:3001/chefs/peter (shows the chef profile **based on username**)
http://localhost:3001/chefs/edit (can edit their profile if logged)
```

How to prevent user to create a username that already has a action name like **edit**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there should be more than one solution but using exclusion validation should work.

```
validates :name, :exclusion => { :in => %w(edit show) }
```